# Google Analytics campaign advice

Tags: google-analytics

I am buying traffic from a broker not one source and sending to various landing pages.

I would like to know the best way to structure a campaign so I can find which referrering site/URL is performing the best (time on site, bounce etc.).

Should the `utm_campaign` be the 'brokername' and the `utm_source` be the 'landingpagename' or should this be the other way around?

Also what would be the best way to create a custom report to show all the referrers metrics by each landing page?

Comment: Will the utm_source override the referral URL and if so then in this case it might be best to leave this out?

Comment: Can anyone see a downside to letting google automatically discover the referrer and me setting a custom parameter to the landing page ie, site.com?campaign=brokername and then creating a custom report based on those URLS that contain that brokername ?

Comment: you could be getting traffic from other pages off the same source and you won't be able to differentiate between that traffic and your bought traffic without specifying the utm parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If it was me I would run a small test as I think both approaches will work.

`utm_source` will override the referral URL as far as I am aware as you use it to set custom source.

Your second approach looks fine as well and is probably a little less effort once you have the report set-up.

It would be good to know what you go with in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would use the campaigns:

1. page 1 - `utm_source` = brokername, `utm_medium` = affiliate, `utm_campaign` = testpage1
2. page 2 - `utm_source` = brokername, `utm_medium` = affiliate, `utm_campaign` = testpage2